# JavaScript Object/ Class/ Getter methods

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, объекты, getter

Мне нужно выполнить эти задания чтобы пройти собеседование в одной компании, на первую работу.

Вот задания:

1. Используйте класс `Person` и расширьте его для классов `Employee` и
   `Customer`;
2. Объект `Person` имеет приватное свойство `name` и `getter` метод для
   `name`.
3. Класс `Employee` имеет две приватные свойства: `hire date`(дата
   принятия на работу) и `salary`(зарплата). Они также имеют методы
   `getter` для этих свойств.
4. Класс `Customer` имеет приватное свойство `contract number` (номер
   договора) и `getter` для номера договора.

```js
//4)Create a Person class
class Person{
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstname = firstName;
  this.lastname = lastName;
  this._name = name; // create a private name property for the Person class


// create a getter method for the name for the Person class
  this.getName = function () {
    return this._name;
};

  this.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstname+ " " + this.lastname;
  };
}
}

// extend Person class for the Employee and Customer classes.

class Employee extends Person {
  constructor(_hireDate, _salary){
  this._hiredate = hireDate; // create a private property hire date for  Employee class
  this._salary = salary; // create a private property salary for  Employee class

  // create a getter method for the hire date
  this.getHireDate = function(){
  return this._hiredate;
};
  // create a getter method for the salary
  this.getSalary = function(){ 
  return this._salary;
};
}
}


class Customer extends Person {
constructor(){

this._contractNumber = contractNumber; // create a private contract number for Customer class


//create a  getter for the contract number.
this.getcontractNumber = function(){
return this._contractNumber;
};
};
}
```

Вроде сделал как знаю на данный момент, но выдаёт ошибки.
Я закрепил фото. Может у кого-то есть советы и подскажете как сделать правильно.

[image: error]

Comment: На русский переведите пожалуйста. А в extended Classes вам надо прежде чем к this обращатся, вызвать [super()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super). И return там не нужен

Comment: На русский мне будет тяжело всё перевести, о постараюсь. Мне нужно выполнить эти задания что бы пройти собеседование в одной компаний, на первую работу) Вот задания:
1) Используйте класс Person и расширьте его для классов Employee и Customer;
2) Объект Person имеет приватное свойство "name" и getter метод для "name".
3) Класс Employee имеет  две приватные свойства: "hire date"(дата принятия на работу) и "salary"(зарплата). Они также имеют методы getter для этих своиств.

Comment: 4)Класс Customer имеет приватное свойство "contract number" (номер договора) и getter для номера договора.
Вроде сделал как знаю на данный момент, но выдаёт ошибки. Я закрепил фото. И может у кого-то есть советы, и скажет как сделать правильно. Буду очень благодарен всем.

Comment: Это всё надо не в комментариях писать, а в тексте вопроса, с помощью кнопки править. Вопросы на английском тут закрывают. Попробуйте с super, может быть вопросы отпадут

Comment: спасибо за подсказки, сейчас попробую с "super();" может выйдет.

Comment: TLDR: super - это вызов конструктора класса родителя

Answer (score 1):

Bроде сейчас попробовал добавил "super()", и уже не выдаёт ошибку, и можно создавать новый объекты  с классом Customer и Employee ) вроде работает, надеюсь правильно сделал.

```js
class Person{
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstname = firstName;
  this.lastname = lastName;
  this._name = name; // create a private name property for the Person class


// create a getter method for the name for the Person class
  this.getName = function () {
return this._name;
};

  this.getFullName = function() {
return this.firstname+ " " + this.lastname;
  };
}
}

// extend Person class for the Employee and Customer classes.
class Employee extends Person {
  constructor(hireDate, salary){

  super(hireDate, salary);
  this._hiredate = hireDate; // create a private property hire date for  Employee class
  this._salary = salary; // create a private property salary for  Employee class

  // create a getter method for the hire date s
  this.getHireDate = function(){
  return this._hiredate;
};
  // create a getter method for the salary
  this.getSalary = function(){  //varianta alternativa:  Employee.prototype.getSalary = function(){
  return this._salary;
};
}
}


class Customer extends Person {
constructor(contractNumber){

super(contractNumber);
this._contractNumber = contractNumber; // create a private contract number for Customer class


//create a  getter for the contract number.
this.getcontractNumber = function(){
return this._contractNumber;
};
};
}
```